# Laravel 4 - NotFoundHttpException only on one custom route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I must be missing something really simple but I can't seem to find it. So I have my Resource defined in my routes.php but I need an additional route for an advanced search page with filters and stuff, my show/update/edit/create... pages are working perfectly but my search page isn't.

So in routes I have:

```
 Route::resource('hostesses', 'HostessesController');
 Route::get('/hostesses/search', 'HostessesController@search');
```

And I have a search form on my main page like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'hostesses.search', 'class' => 'navbar-form navbar-right')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::text('search_term', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array("class"=>'btn btn-default')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And when I use the search form I get the NotFoundHttpException

In my controller I have:

```
public function search()
{

    return View::make('hostesses.search');

}
```

And I have created the template on views/hostesses/search.blade.php with a simple hello world message to check that it works, but I keep getting the exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your routes and 'define' the named route of `hostesses.search` which is in your form

```
Route::any('/hostesses/search', array(['as' => 'hostesses.search', 'uses' => 'HostessesController@search');
Route::resource('hostesses', 'HostessesController');
```

Because what is happening is the resource for `/hostesses/$id` is capturing the `search` id, and returning an error that `id` of `search` does not exist

Also - change your route to `Route::any()`. This means it will respond to "get" and "post" requests.

However I would recommend splitting your route to be `getSearch()` and `postSearch()` functions and do this:

```
Route::get('/hostesses/search', array(['as' => 'hostesses.getsearch', 'uses' => 'HostessesController@getSearch');
Route::post('/hostesses/search', array(['as' => 'hostesses.postsearch', 'uses' => 'HostessesController@postSearch');
Route::resource('hostesses', 'HostessesController');


public function getSearch()
{
   return View::make('hostesses.search');
}

public function postSearch()
{
      // Do validation on form
      // Get search results and display
}
```

And update your form

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'hostesses.postsearch', 'class' => 'navbar-form navbar-right')) }}
```

Comment: Change it to Route::any()

Comment: Oh - I just realised - you are using named route but havent defined it - check my updated answer

Comment: I'm getting Route [hostesses.search] not defined. on my form page, the code you posted is the same I had for my form, I think

Comment: Yeah - i updated my answer already - check the new code - you need to define the route name if you are going to use it.

Comment: Yeah, it works now, thanks! So what would be the difference between getSearch and postSearch?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53951/discussion-between-elaine-marley-and-the-shift-exchange)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a POST route:

```
Route::post('/hostesses/postSearch',array('as'=>'hostesses.search','uses' => 'HostessesController@postSearch'));
```

Then in your controller

```
public function postSearch()
{

    var_dump(Input::get('search_term'));

}
```

Comment: why did you change the name of the function/route? May that be part of the problem? I do get the var_dump output, but if I change that to return View::make('hostesses.search'); I get a white page

Comment: I did not change it, you should keep your get method because you need a route for displaying your form, and another to obtain the value of input.